# C++ Threads and Simple blocking mechanism?

Tags: c++, multithreading, blocking

I have a program in C++ that runs a bunch of threads to manipulate the same data. Each of these threads have a pointer to an object that is being manipulated, for example:

thread1 and thread2 both have a pointer to object1
object1->addSomething() can be used by either thread1 or 2 and refer to the same object

Now, these operations might give some trouble if they are being done at the same moment by both threads, so I want a simple mechanism for blocking. What I want is simply this:

```
void method()
{
  waitUntilFree()
  blockForOthers()
  doSomething()
  unblock()
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I just want to block and wait until it is free. I don't mind that the thread might have to wait a while. Is there an easy mechanism to do this? I use Boost for these threads but I couldn't for the life of me figure out a way to do this (seemlingly) simple block-and-wait thing.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by Ferruccio you can use a [Mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) like [`Boost.Mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) from the same library for synchronization:

```
class X {
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
public:
    void method() {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
        // ... now locked, do stuff
    } // mutex automatically unlocked when scoped_lock is destructed
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using Boost, you can use a [Boost mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts) to protect simultaneous access by multiple threads.

Then use a join() on each thread to wait for it to complete.

```
// create the mutex where it can be accessed by all threads
boost::mutex lock;

// in each thread
lock.lock();
// do something with shared data
lock.unlock();

// for each thread
thread.join(); // wait for thread to finish
```

Comment: Why join if exclusive access is desired? In that case a simple RAII-style [`mutex::scoped_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) is much better suited.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche - agreed. scoped_lock is better. I just wanted to keep the example simple. As for the join, I guess it's just a practice I've fallen into, always waiting for threads to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Use **mutex**.

More information about it you can find at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *functionC();
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int  counter = 0;

main()
{
   int rc1, rc2;
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   /* Create independent threads each of which will execute functionC */

   if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
   }

   if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
   }

   /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
   /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
   /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

   exit(0);
}

void *functionC()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
   counter++;
   printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
}
```

Comment: That's C rather than C++ (it's int main() in C++), but a nice little example for the POSIX API.  Perhaps somebody should mention that mutex stands for mutual exclusion, any one thread holding the lock excludes others from acquiring it....

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for so-called mutexes. These come as part of the thread library. Have a look at [this dr. dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401518;jsessionid=Q5EFQBESEUUPTQE1GHRSKHWATMY32JVN).